# Angular 5 typescript call service within a service and combine data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to call a service within a service and combine the data.  The two services are 1) shipDateChangeService and 2) applicantService.  I store the data from each service in shipClasses and applicantClasses respectively.  I then want to combine the data and store it in a results array.  I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to do this and since I'm new to Angular and typescript it has been going well.  Below is what I currently have but I'm running into scoping problems and I don't want to create too many loops.

**UPDATE**  I forgot to mention that data from the first call will be used to request data from the second call.

Code:

```
    this.result = [];
    this.shipClasses = [];
    this.applicantClasses = [];

    this.shipDateChangeService
            .getShipDateChangeClasses(query)
            .finally(() => {
                this.blockResults = false;
                this.shipClasses.forEach(function(value, key) {
                    this.push({'indSsn' : value.indSsn, 'ofcSymbId' : value.ofcSymbId, 'recstaLocCd' : value.recstaLocCd, 'rctgStnId' : value.rctgStnId, 'tngShipDt' : value.tngShipDt, 'name' : '' });
                    this.applicantService.getApplicant(value.indSsn)
                    .finally(() => {
                        console.log('within 2nd finally');
                    })
                    .subscribe(applicantList => (this.applicantClasses = applicantList));

                }, this.results);
            })
            .subscribe(classList => (this.shipClasses = classList));
```

Comment: what is the return type of `getShipDateChangeClasses` and `getApplicant`, promise?, obeservable?

Comment: Maybe you could create a small example : https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: the return type of each is observable.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way

When you API calls are **not dependent** on another API param the you can use this.

```
forkJoin()
```

With the use of `forkJoin` you can call multiple API at a time and you will get response in array.

Ex.

```
forkJoin(API_1 , API_2)
.subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
```

You can find more [Here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

When you have dependent res to another API then follow this.

```
POST('url', data).pipe(
   concatMap(result1 => secondPOSTCallToAPI('url', result1))
   concatMap( result2 => thirdPOSTCallToAPI('url', result2))
   concatMap(result3 => fourthPOSTCallToAPI('url', result3))
  ....
 ).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
 });
```

This is works for me.!

Comment: I tried this but got an error saying _Property 'indSsn' does not exist on type 'ShipDateChangeClass[]'._ :

`this.shipDateChangeService.
   .getShipDateChangeCLasses(query).pipe(
       concatMap(shipDateChangeResults => this.applicantService.getApplicant(shipDateChangeResults.indSsn))
)
.subscribe(finalResults => (this.results  = finalResults));`

Answer (score 0):

If the two service calls are not dependent on each other then you can have multiple parallel API calls and use `forkjoin` to combine all results into a single array. If the two calls are dependent, use `switchMap`